# Watching movies {on/of/in/with} a specific genre

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am looking for the correct preposition to use in a sentence I am including in my short bio.

The sentence goes like this:

"My other hobbies include cycling, hiking, cooking and **watching movies ___ sci-fi genre**."

Similarly for "[...] **reading books ___ sci-fi genre**."

Which preposition would best fit in the above two sentences (does it depend on action i.e. reading/watching)? I have a hunch that it should be either 'on' or 'of'.

Comment: Why not just "watching sci-fi movies"?

Comment: @ThePhoton I would like to use the word 'genre' in the sentence

Comment: *From* is fine. *Of* can work. *In* can work but not here. *With* means the genre is sitting next to you, the two of you watching together a movie whose category is unspecified. *On* can mean that you're sitting not next to the genre but atop of it, or (more likely) that the movie you're watching is a documentary *about* the genre. Whose genre, then, is not the genre but "documentary".

Comment: I would say of (if I had to use genre - I would rather say "scifi books").  As RegDwight says, on implies documentary.  I have not heard from used, but wouldn't say it's wrong.  However, I think you need to use "the" for all of them: "books/movies of the sci-fi genre"

Comment: cycling, cooking, hiking and movie watching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct obvious way to say this is "... watching sci-fi movies".

It is possible to say "... watching movies from the sci-fi genre", or perhaps "...in the sci-fi genre", but there is no reason to structure your phrase like this. ("on" would mean watching documentaries about sci-fi movies)

Don't force your grammar to use a particular word. That is "putting the cart before the horse".

Comment: *In a more cerebral movie, Moon outshines other movies **in the sci-fi genre**...* [source](http://www.tasteofcinema.com/2019/the-10-best-indie-sci-fi-films-of-the-21st-century/) The examples I can find of "from the sci-fi genre" are almost all user comments and blog posts (as opposed to edited articles from the press). Not saying "from" isn't possible, but "in" might be preferred. We could also say "sci-fi genre movies" if we really wanted to use genre.

Comment: But you aren't *watching* the movie *in* the genre.  So the movie is in the genre but in this particular collocation "from" is preferred (I feel, but "in" would communicate perfectly well, so I've added it back).But this is sort of the point - don't use the word genre at all.

Comment: I had trouble finding any strong evidence one way or the other from the free resources I have access to - NGrams was a bust because getting really specific led to no results and being less specific resulted in mostly irrelevant (based on context) results. I probably would use "from" in that exact sentence, although I would never express it that way. I *would* say something like "I like sci-fi movies, especially those in the hard-science subgenre."

Comment: sci-fie moving watching, to go with the gerunds....

Answer (score 0):

> movies **in** the sci-fi genre.

Categories such as genres are logical containers, and we use “in” with containers, whether they are physical or logical.